# Parameter tuning in simulink real-time

Tags: matlab, performance, parameters, real-time, simulink

I have several large-scale-model, that each model shows a Generation (171A00,181B30,...) and has its own parameters (approximately 200 parameters that includes values, matrix, ...) .
I have changed them to struct in order to separate parameters of each generation from other ones ( because most parameters have identical name) . However, the values of parameters are different in each project. There are also global parameters as variables in base workspace.
Moreover, geneartions work as enable subsystems.
I need to change these parameters with new ones from another project.
I'd like to know, if it is possible to change parameters programmatically in stand-alone mode. (i.e.) I transmit model on USB and connect USB in Target PC and then change parameters with a script in MATLAB.

p.s: this solution does not work : `set_param('vdp/Mu','Gain','10')`
It is really difficult to find where a parameter is used. ( as a gain, as a break Point in lookup-table, or …) That’s why this solution is not possible.

For example:

Project 1:

```
P181. AV_BILIM_POT_EXTENSION_Thermal = 4000;
```

Or

```
P181.BmsCurLimn_BatSocMaxSp_P = [0 0.02 0.232 0.492 0.692 0.742 0.793 0.845 0.897 0.999 1];

P171. AV_BILIM_POT_EXTENSION_Thermal = 2000 (dummy)
P171. BmsCurLimn_BatSocMaxSp_P = dummy
```

Project 2:

```
P181. AV_BILIM_POT_EXTENSION_Thermal = 3000;
P181.BmsCurLimn_BatSocMaxSp_P = [0 0.04 0.45 0.52 0.653 0.732 0.756 0.823 0.867 0.965 1];

P171. AV_BILIM_POT_EXTENSION_Thermal = 2000 (dummy)
P171. BmsCurLimn_BatSocMaxSp_P = dummy
```

Project 3:

```
P181. AV_BILIM_POT_EXTENSION_Thermal = dummy
P181.BmsCurLimn_BatSocMaxSp_P = dummy

P171. AV_BILIM_POT_EXTENSION_Thermal = 1000
P171. BmsCurLimn_BatSocMaxSp_P = [0 0.01 0.23 0.42 0.553 0.832 0.856 0.923 1]
```

Project 4:
This project could have a real value for both generation.(not dummy)

Thanks,

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to reformulate your question according to the guidelines provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, I would improve on formatting for better readability.